# Pull first Image from {Body} / Tumblr Posts

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, themes, tumblr

is there a way to pull the first image from any post aka {Body} (similar to wordpress' featured image) for use as a thumbnail somewhere?

my plan is to only show the first image from every post with post title only on the index page.

possibly with the use of json or jquery or sth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this help you

```
$("img:first")
```

check this [jquery selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) out